# Showing large image

Tags: android, media

I load an image from resource folder via:

```
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.imagename);
```

It works for regular images, but if I try with a large file (2100*1600), it would not show. In the debugger, I can see the picture in the "bmp" variable but it does not show on the device nor does it give any error message. But if I move the source file to the drawable-xxhdpi folder - then it shows properly. So far so good. However when the user selects a custom image from his pictures, larger images still do not work. I load from the pictures folder via:

```
bmp = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
```

The drawable-xxhdpi workaround does not apply here. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: the image is likely too large for the device. You can try to load it pre-scaled

Comment: are you sure the small images selected by the user are shown properly.. ? because i guess fileprovider is required to access the memory ...since nougat

Comment: You better down scale the image. Check out this [https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap]

Comment: Scaling down is not an option. I need the image in full resolution. I use a TouchImageView to show it, so the user can zoom and pan as needed.

Comment: And yes, small images selected by the user work perfectly.

Comment: You can try webview to render the full image, load it using `file:///` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it for me was to add

```
android:hardwareAccelerated = "false"
```

to the application tag in the AndroidManifest.xml. Apparently the API tries to load the image as texture to OpenGL – or something like that.
Now the app is slow, but at least everything works.